# Cannot trigger BroadcastReceiver in stopped state with FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES flag

Tags: android-intent, intentfilter, android-broadcastreceiver

Use-Case :

> Launching an operation background when a button is clicked. The >operation resides in `BroadcastReceiver` in `Application1` and the >Intent is being broadcasted from `Application2`.

Application2 `BroadcastReceiver` :

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Receiver triggered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Application2 `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<receiver
android:name="com.my.package.MyBroadcastReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="my.custom.action" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Application1 `sendMyBroadcast()` (called on button click) :

```
public void sendMyBroadcast(){
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sending broadcast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent =  new Intent("my.custom.action");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
        this.getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

I also tried testing my `BroadcastReceiver` from adb with the following command :
`adb shell am broadcast -a my.custom.action --include-stopped-packages`

Even the above command is unable to trigger the BroadcastReceiver. But if I launch the application once and then close it, then the above command is able to trigger the BroadcastReceiver.

**p.s :** As you can see from the code, I am broadcasting the intent from a `Fragment`, though I don't think that should make any difference.
EDIT : Also tried using an explicit intent and still didn't work

```
public void sendMyBroadcast(){
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sending broadcast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent =  new Intent("my.custom.action");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
        ComponentName component = new ComponentName("com.my.package", "com.my.package.MyBroadcastReceiver");
        intent.setComponent(component);
        this.getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```